# Example JSON HTTP request for twitter api?

Tags: json, twitter

I want to make a request to the twitter api. This is the example provided in the documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search):

```
GET:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed
```

There is no example request on the documentation. How would the request for this url be including an alert with data response?

Comment: I don't get what you exactly need. What's missing for you? It's a JSON encoded object. You just need to know the whole structure. Look here a more "visible" information of the response: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed

Comment: I don't know how to do the request. I tried simple ajax and doesn't work. I'm not saying I'm doing right, on the contrary I'm sure I'm not so I just want an example of a request of a json object to know how it's done

Comment: Are you using javascript/jquery? php?

Comment: I'm using jquery and php. I'm trying to do the request with both js and jquery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look if this helps, I made an example for you:

Basically the HTML code contains 2 inputs. one for the button and one for the query string.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="padding: 20px;">
        <input id="query" type="text" value="blue angels" />
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" />
    </div>
    <div id="tweets" style="padding: 20px;">
        Tweets will go here.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After pressing the search button, you'll send a request to twitter asking for 5 results (rpp) containing the query string.

Here's the javascript for this page:

```
function searchTwitter(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + jQuery.param(query),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var tweets = $('#tweets');
            tweets.html('');
            for (res in data['results']) {
                tweets.append('<div>' + data['results'][res]['from_user'] + ' wrote: <p>' + data['results'][res]['text'] + '</p></div><br />');
        }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var params = {
            q: $('#query').val(),
            rpp: 5
        };
        // alert(jQuery.param(params));
        searchTwitter(params);
    });
});
```

The trick is the jQuery.param() function that you'll pass the params for the search/request

See it running here:

http://jsfiddle.net/73L4c/6/

Answer (score 12):

This does not work anymore since Twitter announced API 1.1. Look at this question to learn to use API 1.1: [Need help converting to Twitter API v1.1 - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207850/need-help-converting-to-twitter-api-v1-1-javascript)