# Get Twitter Feed as JSON without authentication

Tags: javascript, twitter

I wrote a small JavaScript a couple of years ago that grabbed a users (mine) most recent tweet and then parsed it out for display including links, date etc.

It used this json call to retrieve the tweets and it no longer works.

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/radfan.json
```

It now returns the error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

I have looked at using the api version (code below) but this requires authentication which I would rather avoid having to do as it is just to display my latest tweet on my website which is public anyway on my profile page:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/radfan.json
```

I haven't kept up with Twitter's API changes as I no longer really work with it, is there a way round this problem or is it no longer possible?

Comment: Can't do this anymore. Here's how to do it now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049821/setting-up-twitter-api-getting-the-last-few-tweets

Comment: @SimonBarker it is possible to use a json call to retrieve the tweets. I have just post an answer about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth), using the REST API you'll need [OAuth Tokens](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens) in order to do this. Luckily, we can use [the Search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) (which doesn't use OAuth) and use the `from:[USERNAME]` operator

<del>Example:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:marcofolio

Will give you a JSON object with tweets from that user, where</del>

```
object.results[0]
```

<del>will give you the last tweet.</del>

Comment: All API methods now require authentication.

Comment: @PaulSchreiber I just post a working alternative to the deprecated : `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=`

Comment: Looks like that since 1.1 requests to api must be identified. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search: "Please note that now API v1.1 requires that the request must be authenticated"

Comment: This worked really well for me, hope it helps someone! https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher

Comment: {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

Answer (score 17):

Previously the **Search API** was the only Twitter API that didn't require some form of **OAuth**. Now it does require auth.

Twitter's **Search API** is acquired from a third party acquisition - they rarely support it and are seemingly unenthused that it even exists. On top of that, there are many limitations to the payload, including but not limited to a severely reduced set of **key:value** pairs in the **JSON** or **XML** file you get back.

When I heard this, I was shocked. I spent a LONG time figuring out how to use the least amount of code to do a simple **GET** request (like displaying a timeline).

I decided to go the **OAuth** route to be able to ensure a relevant payload. You need a server-side language to do this. **JavaScript** is visible to end users, and thus it's a bad idea to include the necessary **keys** and **secrets** in a .js file.

I didn't want to use a big library so the answer for me was **PHP** and help from @Rivers' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/14007402#14007402). The answer below it by @lackovic10 describes how to include queries in your authentication.

I hope this helps others save time thinking about how to go about using Twitter's API with the new **OAuth** requirement.

Comment: According to [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets), even search methods now require authentication.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. OAuth is now required for all Twitter API's. It's my impression that OAuth is significantly easier to accomplish on Ruby than on PHP, if anyone is trying to decide how best to approach it.

Answer (score 14):

You can access and scrape Twitter via advanced search without being logged in:

- https://twitter.com/search-advanced

**GET request**

When performing a basic search request you get:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=Babylon%205&src=typd
```

- q (our query encoded)
- src (assumed to be the source of the query, i.e. typed)

by default, Twitter returns top 25 results, but if you click on
`all` you can get the realtime tweets:

```
https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=Babylon%205&src=typd
```

**JSON contents**

More Tweets are loaded on the page via AJAX:

```
https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=Babylon%205&src=typd&include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&last_note_ts=85&max_position=TWEET-553069642609344512-553159310448918528-BD1UO2FFu9QAAAAAAAAETAAAAAcAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Use `max_position` to request the next tweets

The following json array returns all you need to scrape the contents:

```
https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=Babylon%205&src=typd
```

- has_more_items (bool)
- items_html (html)
- max_position (key)
- refresh_cursor (key)

**DOM elements**

Here comes a list of `DOM elements` you can use to extract

The authors twitter handle

```
div.original-tweet[data-tweet-id]
```

The name of the author

```
div.original-tweet[data-name]
```

The user ID of the author

```
div.original-tweet[data-user-id]
```

Timestamp of the post

```
span._timestamp[data-time]
```

Timestamp of the post in ms

```
span._timestamp[data-time-ms]
```

Text of Tweet

```
p.tweet-text
```

Number of Retweets

```
span.ProfileTweet-action–retweet > span.ProfileTweet-actionCount[data-tweet-stat-count]
```

Number of Favo

```
span.ProfileTweet-action–favorite > span.ProfileTweet-actionCount[data-tweet-stat-count]
```

**Resources**

- https://code.recuweb.com/2015/scraping-tweets-directly-from-twitter-without-authentication/

Comment: when I tried "https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=realtime&q=Babylon%205&src=typd". It doesn't give scroll_cursor. How I can get the next page content.

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar Check the blog linked at the foot of the post. It now uses max_position instead of scroll_cursor. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution isn't useful for anything JS based due to CORS enforcement.

Comment: Indeed, it is a server side solution to be used with `file_get_contents()` for example

Comment: How to order tweets by recent date?

Answer (score 6):

If you're still looking for unauthenticated tweets in JSON, this should work:
https://github.com/cosmocatalano/tweet-2-json

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick hack (really a hack, should be used with caution as its not future proof) which uses http://anyorigin.com to scrape twitter site for the latest tweets.

http://codepen.io/JonOlick/pen/XJaXBd

It works by using anyorigin (you have to pay to use it) to grab the HTML. It then parses the HTML using jquery to extract out the relevant tweets.

Tweets on the mobile site use a div with the class .tweet-text, so this is pretty painless.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=mobile.twitter.com/JonOlick&callback=?', function(data){

  // Remap ... utf8 encoding to ascii. 
  var bar = data.contents;
  bar = bar.replace(/â€¦/g, '...');

  var el = $( '<div></div>' );
  el.html(bar);

  // Change all links to point back at twitter
  $('.twitter-atreply', el).each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('href', "https://twitter.com" + $(this).attr('href'))
  });

  // For all tweets
  $('.tweet-text', el).each(function(i){
    // We only care about the first 4 tweets
    if(i < 4) {
      var foo = $(this).html();
      $('#test').html($('#test').html() + "<div class=ProfileTweet><div class=ProfileTweet-contents>" + foo + "</div></div><br>");
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Twitter API wrapper, such as [TweetJS.com](https://www.TweetJS.com) which offers a limited set of the Twitter API's functionality, but does not require authentication. It's called like this;

```
TweetJs.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline("PetrucciMusic",
function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the twitter api v1 to take the tweets without using OAuth. For example: [this](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&trim_user=true&screen_name=jack&page=0&count=100) link turns @jack's last 100 tweets.

The timeline documentation is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Comment: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview."

Answer (score -4):

The method "GET statuses/user_timeline" need a user Authentification like you can see on the official documentation :

You can use the search method "GET search" wich not require authentification.

You have a code for starting here : http://jsfiddle.net/73L4c/6/

```
function searchTwitter(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + jQuery.param(query),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var tweets = $('#tweets');
            tweets.html('');
            for (res in data['results']) {
                tweets.append('<div>' + data['results'][res]['from_user'] + ' wrote: <p>' + data['results'][res]['text'] + '</p></div><br />');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var params = {
            q: $('#query').val(),
            rpp: 5
        };
        // alert(jQuery.param(params));
        searchTwitter(params);
    });
})
```

Comment: stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890257/example-json-http-request-for-twitter-api