# how to get or acquire tweets as JSON or XML?

Tags: json, xml, nosql, twitter4j, basex

I'm intrigued by BaseX [documention](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Twitter) on Twitter utilizing a JSON module for [converting](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON_Module) to XML -- but how was the data acquired?

To populate a database with tweets, for similar results, what's most expedient method?  (For expediant, read quick-and-dirty [without](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13454287/262852) tokens.)

Comment: I'm not sure this answer your question, but the documentation you link to says, among other things: " Twitter provides the developer community with a set of APIs for retrieving the data about its users and their communication, including the Streaming API for data-intensive applications, the Search API for querying and filtering the messaging content, and the REST API for accessing the core primitives of the Twitter platform." Could that be it?

Comment: As far as I know, twitter data is not available via any API without using authentication tokens.

Comment: heh, back on the 12th, same day, twitter approved my account.  So I'll check this out.  thanks.